# Move the head node from a first linked list to the back of a second linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, append, singly-linked-list

When a certain if statement is passed i have to remove the head node from my first linked-list "new_queue" and add this to the back of my second linked-list "ready_queue".

When I try this the head gets removed from "new_queue" but it does not get added to the back of "ready_queue", instead it always just replaces the second node in "ready_queue".

I think this is because of the line `ready_queue_prev -> next = NULL;`, but if I remove this line the whole linked list will be put at the back of "ready_queue" instead of just the node.

Anyone know how to solve this?

```
typedef struct ST_PCB {
  int arrival_time;
  char name[9];
  int duration;
  struct ST_PCB * next;
} T_PCB;


int main(void){
    // serial list of newly arrived tasks
    T_PCB * new_queue = NULL;
    // circular list of active tasks
    T_PCB * ready_queue = NULL;
    // extra state needed to switch tasks 
    // from new_queue to ready_queue when they're started
    T_PCB * ready_queue_prev = NULL;

    //this constructs the linked-list and sorts it by arrival time
    new_queue = read_tasks();
    new_queue = sort_tasks_on_arrival(new_queue);


    if(something happends...){
        if(ready_queue != NULL){
            ready_queue_prev = new_queue;
            new_queue = new_queue->next;      
            ready_queue -> next = ready_queue_prev;
            ready_queue_prev -> next = NULL;
        }
        else{
            ready_queue = new_queue;
            new_queue = new_queue->next;
            ready_queue->next = NULL;     
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the back of the queue for you? Is that the side of the head, or of the tail?

Comment: With the back of the queue I mean the side of the tail, I'm sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a certain if statement is passed i have to remove the head node
> from my first linked-list "new_queue" and add this to the back of my
> second linked-list "ready_queue".

To add a node to the tail of a linked list you have to find the tail.

First of all actually you need to check whether `new_queue` is not equal to `NULL`. If it is equal to `NULL` then there is nothing to append. The if statement (without any else because it is not required) can look the following way

```
    if ( new_queue != NULL)
    {
        T_PCB *tmp = new_queue;
        new_queue = new_queue->next;
        tmp->next = NULL;

        T_PCB **current = &ready_queue;
        while ( *current != NULL ) current = &( *current )->next;
        *current = tmp;     
    }
```

Comment: @Rubeng. It is a too large question to be described in a comment. You should ask a new question at SO.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is indeed making the node the second one in the list:

```
ready_queue -> next = ready_queue_prev;
```

`ready_queue` is the head of the queue, not the tail. You need to first find out where is the tail, and then do that assignment there:

```
T_PCB * tail = ready_queue;
while (tail->next != NULL) {
    tail = tail->next;
}
// We found the tail. Now make the assignment to `next`:
tail->next = ready_queue_prev;
// And now continue with what you had:
ready_queue_prev->next = NULL;
```